# Rails app cant detect local gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, gemfile

This is a very odd one and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Basically, I am able to install gems and use them normally within any folder except those created with rails. It's very very odd. It's difficult to explain so maybe this console output will explain

```
    passenger@rubyserve:~/railsapps$ ls
    app  test_application  testing
    passenger@rubyserve:~/railsapps$ rails -v
    Rails 3.2.2
    passenger@rubyserve:~/railsapps$ 
    passenger@rubyserve:~/railsapps$ 
    passenger@rubyserve:~/railsapps$ cd app/
   passenger@rubyserve:~/railsapps/app$ ls -a
   .   app     config.ru  doc      Gemfile.lock  lib  public    README.rdoc  test  vendor
   ..  config  db         Gemfile  .gitignore    log  Rakefile  script       tmp
    passenger@rubyserve:~/railsapps/app$ 
    passenger@rubyserve:~/railsapps/app$ 
    passenger@rubyserve:~/railsapps/app$ rails -v
    The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  To run 'rails' please ask your administrator to install the package 'rails'
    passenger@rubyserve:~/railsapps/app$
```

It makes bugger all sense. When outside my rails folder, I can call rails to make a new application but once within, rails isn't detected. This is the same for all gems including bundler.

My first thought was that somehow, rails had some specific gem folder hidden away, so I done my gem install from within the rails project, however this didn't work either.

Any thoughts?

---

My setup is ubuntu server 10.10 (I know, i know)
Ruby 1.9.2
gem 1.8.17
and I'm using the latest rvm from wayneeseguin.`enter code here`

Comment: is there a .rvmrc file in your app's folder?

Comment: @FrederickCheung There is not. I've changed the output to ls-a so you can see the full directory

Comment: Ah, I was not aware that you had to specify which rvm gemset to use in a rails folder  'rvm use ruby-1.9.2-pxxxxx'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of problem some time occurs i think u can save a lot of time by [installing and using RVM](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/)

After installing RVM create gemset directory every time whenever you create separate project. e.g you create application blog first you create gemset directory with giving this command

```
rvm gemset create blog
```

then you should use this gemset directory and also ruby version as well e.g  you have install ruby 1.9.2 then use this command

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2@blog
```

after that go into directory of blog application and install this gem

```
gem install bundler
```

and also then `bundle install`. so all local gem will be installed into this blog directory under rvm and there will be no conflicts  will be appear.But keep one thing in mind if your platform is ubuntu then this will work

Comment: I just made your answer a bit less like a wall-of-text. I hope you don't mind.